# getting authorisation for google spreadsheet app

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying this quickstart.py example given on the page: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

I have created these credantials:

[image]

I have credentials.json in the same location as quickstart.py

when I run the command `python quickstart.py` I get this authorisation access error.

[image]

How can I fix this Authroisation error?

Comment: This looks like you have modified the project where you are working with to be public and available to external users, if so, then depending on the scopes you will need verification, you better check your consent screen settings as it may show that you need to complete verification, try changing the consent screen to internal testing instead.

Comment: the authorisation error I am getting is at the consent screen.

Comment: Right, I was explaining that you would need to check the production status of the project, if it's on production you may require to complete the verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you created the client credentials json on one user's account.  Yet you are authorizing the application from another user.

Because your application is still in test and has not been verified yet you need to add each user as a test user over in the google developer console.

Under the Oauth screen simply add the user:

[image]

Note: you can only have 100 test users and you can not remove someone once they have been added.