# Getting "Error 401: deleted_client The OAuth client was deleted" when accessing Google Sheets from python

Tags: python, google-sheets

I am trying to follow the the Python Quickstart example
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

The article tells me to first create credentials:
https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials

This produces a file called client_secret[longs string of numbers].json

However, my problem is that I don't understand what to do with this file.

There is no mention of it in the python quick start program, which instead refers to token.json and credentials.json.

When I run quickstart.py, I get the error message:

"Authorization Error

Error 401: deleted_client
The OAuth client was deleted."

When searching for that error, I found this article:
[Google Apps Script: "Error 401: deleted_client The OAuth client was deleted" All of a sudden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016751/google-apps-script-error-401-deleted-client-the-oauth-client-was-deleted-all)

However, it does not seem to address my problem - it talks about some project being deleted. I am talking about a situation where I am trying to start everything from scratch.

Also, this questions is related:
[getting authorisation for google spreadsheet app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73404377/getting-authorisation-for-google-spreadsheet-app)
But it is caused by another problem (different users).

Comment: Did you rename the `client_secret[longs string of numbers].json` to `credentials.json`? You need to place this file in the same folder with the `quickstart.py`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, though that of course begs the question why the `quickstart.py` program uses the file name `credentials.json` instead of `client_secret.json`. What I get now is instead `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch`. I will investigate this further.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the problem was that I had created the wrong type of credentials - I have erroneously chosen `web application` instead of `desktop application`. When that was corrected, everything worked as expected.